# Is Dialogflow intermediating requests from Actions on Google?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Consider an agent created on Dialogflow (api.ai) and deployed to Actions on Google. When a user at Google Assistant request some information to this agent, is this request intermediated by Dialogflow? 
I've noted that sometimes the agent response time is too long, so was wondering if it's due to my webhook taking too long to answer, or from Dialogflow on answering to Actions on Google.

Comment: You should monitor your webhook to find out, just let your webserver append the response times to the logfile.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'm pretty sure that my webhook is the major guilty for the delay. But anyway, switching from the Dialogflow to the SDK model, may help a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both requests and responses go through Dialogflow's servers.

However, if there is latency, the chances are high that this is a latency on your side (or between you and Google) rather than Google/Dialogflow's.

Make sure that you're logging both when the request arrives and when you send your response. There are analytics tools that assist with this as well and may be useful for this case.